# Finding peaks and determining noise

Tags: na.numerical-analysis, numerical-linear-algebra, fourier-analysis

Hello ,
   Im having one matrix which is product of two FFT transforms of one fits image ( astronomical image ). In that matrix you could find 3 peaks. One largest in center, and two around central peak. Main problem is determining those peaks. I could find central ( largest ) peak by searching for max value in matrix. But, when i want to find out size of central peak i`m having problem due to noise. Im not sure where noise begin and where peak end. So, my question is how to find noise value? And when i find it, peaks will be above that value.

Comment: Very few people will be able to understand what you're asking here, I expect. I certainly cannot.

Comment: I removed some of the tags whose relevance seemed hard to imagine, but I agree that this question as it stands needs significant elaboration and cleanup to be understandable.

Comment: I changed question, i hope it is much understandable now

Comment: your question is much much more about data analysis techniques then anything else. I suggest you ask instead at http://stats.stackexchange.com/faq or http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/faq (I think the first fits better you needs, but you may decide otherwise). Also, there are established peak fitting softwares available in the wild (Origin, Igor of the general data analysis softwares; R if you want something powerful and used by statisticians). 

Comment: Math. analysis of such questions would require some (probabilistic or determinant) model, otherwise I am afraid it does not make sense. You should make some assumption - like noise is (un)correlated, peaks have the forms: of gaussians or smth... and so on... But making such model I guess the questions will disappear e.g. if peak is Guassian - then it is reasonable to consider [-3sigma, 3 sigma] interval around the peak.... So on

Comment: @ Alexander Chervov   those  peaks are Guassian, but how can I find sigma value?
@ Willie Wong - Ill try asking question there too 
Thank you!

Comment: @victor for example just by "fitting" (e.g. adjust two params of gaussian such that the distance between gaussian and experimental data is minimal (distance usually sum of differences^2, but may be other depending on the model))  or another way - estimate mean and sigma by usual methods somewhere around the peak. Somewhere may be taken ad-hoc or from previous data... I think there can be many many ways... If you have some "model" then you can derive "optimal" method, if do not have model - just choose any method
 